# Hibernate: unnest function not found

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make a query and using postgresql (pgadmin) it works correctly, but not since hibernate (Java Spring JPA). Skips the error that unnset doesn't know

The query I make is the following:

`@Query("select w from Work w where array_length(w.groups, 1) is null or exists (select 1 from unnest(w.groups) n where n = :group)")`

And the error is as follows:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: unnest near line 1, column 123 [select w from org.vin.ns.core.domain.model.Work w where array_length(w.groups, 1) is null or exists (select 1 from unnest(w.groups) n where n = :group)]`

Does anyone know how I can use the unnest function in hibernate?

The groups field in the database is of type text[]

Thanks.

Comment: HQL (or JPQL) knows nothing about database specific functions. You need to create a native query if you want to use `unnest()`

Comment: but there is no alternative to unnest?

Comment: I think there is no alternative to the unnest. you have to use native query.

Answer (score 2):

`unnest` is a postgresql function that can be called just like any other function. For example:

```
@Query("select function('unnest', w.groups) from Work w")
```

Although in the query posted by OP `unnest` is not needed at all. This is how it could be transformed into a valid JPQL.

```
@Query("select w from Work w where w.groups is null or function('in_array', :group, w.groups) = true")
```

Where function `in_array` may be defined as

```
public class MyPostgresqlDialect extends PostgisPG95Dialect {
    public MyPostgresqlDialect() {
        ...
        registerFunction("in_array", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "(?1 = ANY(?2))"));
    }
}
```